# How to model an Android "Intent" in UML Class Diagram

Tags: android, android-intent, uml, class-diagram

In a UML class diagram, how would you display calling another activity with an intent?

Comment: For those interested in UML class diagrams for Android code in general, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340905/android-creating-uml-from-android-java-source-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an interesting paper titled [Engineering Android Applications Based on UML Activities](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-24485-8_14) by Frank Kraemer on using UML activities to model Android applications, including starting activities via intents.

Answer (score 0):

think this is one-way association betwwen activities. Because there is no other way to start activity.