# Android: Creating UML from Android Java source code

Tags: android, uml, argouml

i am looking for a program that can create automatically an Uml from my Java-Android source code.
I have tested ArgoUml, but it does not support Android.

Have any one a suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "ArgoUML doesn't support Android."  There's nothing library specific about the Java reverse engineering.  You could RE the Android JARs (or sources) first so that all references are defined, but I'm not sure that adds much value to your diagram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can second what Tom Morris wrote in the comment above. Even ArgoUML should work. If you need improved (commercial) reverse engineering support you can try [UML Lab](http://www.uml-lab.com/) - it can definitely read Java written for Android and has a free trial and free academic licenses (incl. support). If you have problems with that just comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, no point of trying to find Android specific tool for UML modeling. It doesn't exist and even if you happen to find one, it probably is an immature product.

What you really should be asking, and which has many old answers in other posts, is which product is best for Eclipse?

I did spend my whole current week trying to find either good UML tool or good RAD tool, for Android projects. I did test several products and regarding the UML I did hit to a gold vein yesterday: [Altova UModel 2012](http://www.altova.com/umodel.html)

UModel has pretty simple UI, you can draw all the basic diagram types AND it can round-trip engineer SEQUENCE diagrams too. The last is something none of other products at the same price level (199€) could do, at least not forward engineer them. Probably one of the kind for much more expensive levels too.

It might not be perfect, but the best I have used and definitively worth of checking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Omondo](http://www.uml2.org) works for you. I didn't try it for Java-Android projects, but for usual java projects it works really good. Give it a try.